# Existing a free mean to send email with excel ?

Tags: excel, outlook

I'm a newbie working with excel and I wonder if it is possible to send emails freely with excel, even if combine with outlook or other dependencies,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following should send the active workbook, but I strongly suggest researching this for something that will fit your specific requirement.

```
Sub Mail_workbook()
    ActiveWorkbook.SendMail "someone@somewhere.com","Subject_line"
End Sub
```